# BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION (Transact-SQL)

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-2012

I want to implement BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION (Transact-SQL) for that i have used following query.

```
USE LOXF;
GO
BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION;
-- Delete candidate from local instance.
DELETE DatatbaseName.dbo.TBLUSERPROFILE
    WHERE USERINDEX = 13;
-- Delete candidate from remote instance.
DELETE RemoteServer.DatatbaseName.dbo.TBLUSERPROFILE
    WHERE USERINDEX = 13;
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
GO
```

but when i run above query i got error saying "Could not find server 'RemoteServer' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers".So please let me know where i am wrong.

Comment: You didn't create a linked server to `RemoteServer`, right?

Comment: how can create linked server?please help

Comment: Also in above query what is RemoteServer?It is server instance or reserved keyword.

Comment: This should be the name of the remote server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must create a linked server before issuing queries against it.

This could be done with `sp_addlinkedserver` stored procedure (as the error message stated), or with GUI:

Start SSMS; in Object Explorer, under your server, find Server Objects, then Linked Server, and chose New Linked Server from the context menu.

If the remote server is SQL Server also, it is sufficient to enter the server name. You may need to set the security as well. If you're using windows authentication on both servers, and can normally access the remote server itself, it is sufficient to select "Be made using the login's current security context" radio button.

Comment: BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION (Transact-SQL) same as Two Phase Commit.